# Optimize sql to compare records between two tables and update one table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I need to compare the data between two tables and update one table.  For e.g. the data in DEV (dev_tbl) should be updated with work area table (work_tbl) if any columns (except the primary/unique columns) in work_tbl are modified.

I'm using below update SQL, which works fine when records are less than 20K. The UPDATE statement is slower when record count is > 20K. The max records for update will not exceed 300K.

Is there a efficient way to write the UPDATE statement?  I'm open to PL/SQL FORALL BULK UPDATE as well if performance SQL cannot be tuned.

```
UPDATE dev_tbl t
   SET (t.coll,
        t.co12,
        t.co13,
        col4) =
          (SELECT coll, co12, col3, col4
             FROM work_tbl s
            WHERE t.join_col = s.join_col
               AND t.pk_col = s.pk_col
)
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM work_tbl ss
            WHERE     ss.join_col = s.join_col
                  AND ss.pk_col = s.pk_col
                  AND (col1 || co12 || co13 || col4) NOT IN (SELECT (   col1
                                                                     || col2
                                                                     || col3
                                                                     || col4)
                                                               FROM dev_tbl d
                                                              WHERE ss.join_col =
                                                                       d.join_col))
```

Comment: `(col1 || co12 || co13 || col4)` comparisons are hard to optimize. I'd rewrite that NOT IN as a NOT EXISTS.

Comment: @jarlh.  Thanks.  I did try NOT EXISTS the performance is same as NOT IN

Comment: And you check each column individually? Because `'ab' || 'c' = 'a' || 'bc'`, but  `('ab, 'c') <> ('a', 'bc')`.

Comment: Anyway, table and index definitions are needed, as well as explain plan.

Comment: Index exists on all the join columns.  as you pointed you, the cause of issue is NOT IN and comparing the concatenated column strings

Comment: Exactly, do NOT EXISTS instead, where you compare each column individually.

Comment: Don't see any improvement with NOT EXISTS